# Azimuth normalization

Tags: python, angle, azimuth

I have a table represents the beginning and end of a circle looks like:

```
azimuth | start | stop
 320       70     190
 210      180     300
 100      290      50
```

Using python, I want to normalize it in such a way that the azimuth will be 0 and now the start and stop need to be change.

I tried to change it like:

`new_start = (start-azimuth) mod 360` or

`new_start = (start+azimuth) mod 360`

but I'm not sure which one is the right way?

Any thoughts? did I forget to consider a case where the azimuth is smaller or greater than 180?

Comment: Please tell us, in what language you would like the calculation performed, also it is more likely to get help if you add teh appropriate tag.

Comment: It is not important to me, the formula is the same. I'm using Python right now. What will be the appropriate tag?

Comment: it would be python, I guess? ;-)